# Can PostgreSQL UPDATEs in autocommit mode deadlock?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, deadlock

Is it possible for UPDATEs in PostgreSQL to deadlock when in autocommit mode? If so, how, and why? (Or, why not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is certainly possible if the update affects more than a single table row.

This can come to pass in two ways:

- The query modifies more than a single row in the target table.
- The updated table has a foreign key constraint to another table. In that case, you may end up with a `FOR KEY SHARE` lock on the referenced table.

The deadlock can happen if your statement successfully locks a couple of rows and then blocks on a lock on some other row.

Comment: Do you have an example of queries that deadlock? (I’ve experimented with queries that update tens of thousands of rows, and still they don’t seem to deadlock)

Comment: There must be concurrent transactions. Just start one and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` one of the rows affected by the update. Then wait until the update hangs and try to lock one of the rows already modified by the update.

Comment: Ah: would there be a way of _just_ using autocommit UPDATEs, with no other concurrent transaction, to get a deadlock?

Comment: No. There can never be a deadlock unless there are at least two transactions that can lock each other.

Comment: But isn’t each autocommit SELECT in its own transaction? So if they lock on the same set of multiple rows, and you can get them to attempt to lock them in different orders, then it should be able to deadlock?

Comment: All the transactions in a database session are always one after the other. You need concurrent transactions to get a lock.

Comment: Yes exactly: I do mean if you have two sessions, both in autocommit, then I would think it’s possible for UPDATES to deadlock if they locks the same rows in different orders? (Also: in my previous message I wrote SELECT, but I meant UPDATE. Apologies)

Comment: Yes, it can cause a deadlock. All actions done in one update statements will happen in a single transaction. Try it out as I described above.